# Markov chain - Regular transition matrix

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, ergodic-theory, transition-matrix

[image: Given transition matrix]

I have to prove that this transition matrix is regular but how can I prove it without having to multiply it n times?

I know when you raise it to the 2nd power you have to check if the zeros in the first matrix are at the same entries as in the second one but anyone has a more in depth explanation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A stochastic matrix is regular if it's [irreducible](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/%7Errw1/markov/M.pdf#page12) and has at least one non-zero entry on its main diagonal.  It's easy to show that that your matrix is irreducible, since every state communicates with state $1$, and state $\ i\ $ communicates with state $\ i+1\ $ for $\ i=1,2,3,4\ $, and the first entry on its main diagonal is non-zero.  Therefore it's regular.

Comment: Where in the source you provided exactly is it shown that being irreducible and having a state which self-transitions with positive probability are sufficient conditions for a stochastic matrix to be regular?

Comment: While that source does not give the result in precisely those words,  it does show on [p 34](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/%7Errw1/markov/M.pdf#page38) that an irreducible chain with an aperiodic state is regular, which is a stronger result, because if an entry on the main diagonal of the chain's transition matrix is positive, then the corresponding state must be aperiodic.

Comment: I suppose you mean Lemma 9.6? I don't find the given proof to be very convincing. It is not at all clear what is meant exactly by "sufficiently large $n$." Presumably it means "for all but finitely many positive integers $n$," but the inequality
$$
p_{jk}^{(r+n+s)}\geqslant p_{ji}^{(r)}p_{ii}^{(n)}p_{ik}^{(s)}
$$
is not given any justification. The statement is true, but it nonetheless needs to actually be proven. Because this "answer" simply quotes a source that does not do so, I am downvoting and voting to close.